# Which attacks will nullify Khepri's special?

Tags: smite

I use [Khepri](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Khepri) a lot, specifically in Arena, and I've noticed that some moves nullify his blessing. For example, an ally who is blessed and then gets killed by [Ao Kuang's ultimate](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Ao_Kuang) will not be revived. I assume this has something to do with the "assassination" type of ultimate that Ao Kuang has, but I haven't seen another move consistently nullify the blessing like his ultimate always does.

**Are there any other powers or ultimates that nullify Khepri's special, causing an ally to not be revived?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every spell counted as an execution will nullify the blessing of Khepri.

So yes, there is another, which is Thanatos ultimate, and this is why thanatos came back into the meta, because of all the Khepris.

Feel free to comment if there are other ones I'll add them to the answer, but i'm pretty sure Ao kuang and Thanatos are the only two.